# Why linear equation with weights from a LinearRegressor gives results that are differ from results, that are obtained with the predict method

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression, tflearn

Linear equation:

```
a = linear_regressor.get_variable_value('linear/weight/weight')[0][0]
b = linear_regressor.get_variable_value('linear/bias_weight')[0]

def predict_custom(x):
  return a * x + b
```

And results comparison:

```
linear_regressor.predict(input_fn=input_const(30, WEIGHT_COL))
# array([ 84.63061523], dtype=float32)
predict_custom(30)
# 75.9105224609375
```

Visualization of results, that are obtained via the "predict" method:

[image]

Visualization of results that are obtained via the "predict_custom" method:

[image]

Both of them are alike, but they still differ. Why is this so? If my understanding is correct the "predict" method of the "LinearRegressor" should use same weights that had been used by the "custom_predict" method.